# Can I transfer the value of one variable to another in Javascript

Tags: javascript, numbers, transfer

I'm making a simple game to help learn the basics of Javascript. During the game the player increases "Grain" every time a button is pressed. This value is displayed to the player by a counter named "grainTotal".

What I'd like to do is for the player to be able to press another button and reset the "grainTotal" counter to 0 whilst transferring the original value to another counter - named "storeTotal".

This is what I've tried so far, and whilst it does reset the "grainTotal" counter, all the "storeTotal" counter does is return "[object Object]"

```
function buildStore() { /*transfers the value of grainCount to storeCount and resets grainCount to 0 */

storeCount = {grainCount};
grainCount = 0;
grainTotal = document.getElementById('grain').innerHTML = grainCount;
storeTotal = document.getElementById('storeTotal').innerHTML = storeCount;   
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Can anyone help me see what I'm missing?

Comment: use `.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(grainCount, null, 2)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @Daniel_L why do that??

Comment: Only if we had the power to down vote a comment

Comment: @Daniel_L that doesn't do anything I'm afraid

Comment: because you wouldn't get `[object Object]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you wrapping grainCount in brackets? Just assign the value to storeCount like so:

```
storeCount = grainCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in the end that fixed it, thanks to @Joe-Leonard.

```
function buildStore() { /*transfers the value of grainCount to storeCount and resets grainCount to 0 */

storeCount += grainCount;
grainCount = 0;
grainTotal = document.getElementById('grain').innerHTML = grainCount;
storeTotal = document.getElementById('storeTotal').innerHTML = storeCount;   
}
```

The function does what I wanted it to and the " += " between the storeCount and grainCount means that the current value of the grainTotal is added to the storeTotal instead of just overwriting it.